# Переключатель Switch в диалоговом окне

Tags: c#, android, android-dialog

есть диалоговое окно с Switch и TextView, хочу при переключении Switch отображать или прятать TextView. Ниже приведенный код не работает, пробовал на переключение вешать Toast и он тоже не отображается. Подскажите что я делаю не так, самостоятельные поиски в интернете ни к чему не привели.

```
fabAdd = FindViewById<FloatingActionButton>(Resource.Id.add);

fabAdd.Click += delegate {

LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.From(this);
View view = layoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.user_input_dialog_box, null);
Android.Support.V7.App.AlertDialog.Builder alertbuilder = new Android.Support.V7.App.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
alertbuilder.SetView(view);

var getEdge = view.FindViewById<Switch>(Resource.Id.switchInput);
var info = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.switchInfo);


    alertbuilder.SetCancelable(false)

    .SetPositiveButton(dialog_add, delegate
        {
            getEdge.CheckedChange += delegate(object sender, CompoundButton.CheckedChangeEventArgs e) {

            // var toast = Toast.MakeText(this, "Your answer is " + (e.IsChecked ? "correct" : "incorrect"), ToastLength.Short);
            // toast.Show();

            if (e.IsChecked)
                {
                info.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
                }
            else
                {
                info.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                }
            };
        })
    .SetNegativeButton(dialog_canc, delegate
        {
             alertbuilder.Dispose();
        });
Android.Support.V7.App.AlertDialog dialog = alertbuilder.Create();
dialog.Show();
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все оказалось намного проще, просто перенести getEdge.CheckedChange из раздела SetPositiveButton выше, сразу после объявления Switch и TextView